# What is taxonomy/term/tid/*

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms

I'm first time seeing a link indexed by Google : taxonomy/term/10007/*  as in [here](http://bit.ly/1CBuviE).

What could be causing it?

I've already GlobalRedirect enabled, also not using the View "Taxonomy term" which emulates Drupal core's handling of taxonomy/term.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the "*" from the path *does* trigger the redirection to the right page.

It seems to me the "*" is just confusing global redirect (maybe some setting not configured correctly in the module?), because the redirection is definitely not happening, and that might be the reason why google is indexing that.

I'd suggest double-checking the globalredirect settings in place.

Comment: I've checked - I've set only Default settings in the Globalredirect configuration.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your link rel="canonical" tag. It's setting the core taxonomy path in the href value.

[image: Canonical Location]

link rel="canonical" tells search engines the canonical URL to use for search results. That needs to be fixed to resolve your indexing problem.

Are you use the metatag module? If so, some additional tweaks there should solve the problem.

Comment: No. Which is original source from where Google could have picked taxonomy/term/tid/* url?  And why Drupal is honouring this one?

Comment: If you're using Global Redirect, you should try the **Add Canonical Link** option if you haven't already. Failing that, I know the [metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) provides canonical URLs from path aliases.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but I guess enabling [globalredirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module might solve your problem.

Comment: It is already enabled.